# Setting non-numerical list values

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have a list which I am setting custom numerical values for via code like this inside a `<ol>` tag:

```
<li value="123">Text Here</li>
```

However sometimes the value is empty and I need it to display as either `NNO` or show nothign at all (blank value); however this is proving hard to do.

If I leave it blank it numbers the list normally and if I put `NNO` as the value it does the same thing.

Is there a way to do what I want here? My `doctype` is `html5` if it matters.

**Edit:** To clear it up, whilst the numerical value may be empty at times, the text output between the `li` tags will always be there; so the output I'm looking for would be something like this..

```
123. Text Here
NNO. Text Here
128. Text Here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the list style on those elements with non numerical values to `list-style:none` to show no value.

see this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bpFgS/

Comment: @Brett Check my updated answer for a way to do it with `"NNO. "`. The list markers won't be right-aligned as normal due to the placement inside rather than outside the list elements, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `li` elements only accepts [integers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html) in their value attribute, so it's not possible solely through `li`'s.

Depending on your layout you could simply remove the `list-style` and prepend your own 'value' in a `span` before the rest of your content.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the data inside the list entries in `<span>`s and hide them when the value is blank.

```
li[value=""] span
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26z4W/2/

...Though that works to hide the text instead of the list bullets or numbers, which I just realized is what you wanted. Rooster's answer works for that.

---

Here's one way to do it, based on Rooster's answer but with support for using `"NNO. "` (using `li[value=""]:before {content: "NNO. "}`) instead of having it blank.

http://jsfiddle.net/26z4W/

Uunfortunately, it seems no browser implements [`::marker`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudoelement) yet, but if they do eventually that would make things like this much easier.

Comment: That would hide the entire `li` not just the number